# Mute other application sound when my application is playing sound ios

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer

I am new in playing audio sound. I am stuck in problem where I wanted to **mute other application sound when my application is playing music sound and resume back when I stop my application's sound**. I searched a lot but I could not get any solution.

Below code is for playing audio sound:-

```
var url:NSURL = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("\(soundFile)", ofType: "mp3")!)!
let audioPlayer1 = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: url, error: nil)
audioPlayer1!.numberOfLoops = -1

if(audioPlayer1 == nil)
{
    println("error in playing")
}
else
{
   audioPlayer1!.play()
}
```

Comment: can you please upload some code.

Comment: @chiragshah Please find updated code.

Comment: try with AVAudioSession to mute other application sound.

Answer (score 1):

You need to configure the *AVAudioSession category* :

AVAudioSession Class Reference : http://goo.gl/rh7CX7 . Look for which fit the most for your application. You only need to set it once in your code (make sure it's called).

```
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient, error: nil) // AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient is default
AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, error: nil)
```

If it didn't help, please provide more information (which app isn't mute ? what have you tried ? ...).

Comment: With this different category I would be able to detect sound of other application playing but would it be possible to mute their sounds?

Comment: there are different option which override other application sound so find that option

Comment: `AVAudioSessionCategorySoloAmbient` : _By default, using this category implies that your app’s audio is nonmixable—activating your session will interrupt any other audio sessions which are also nonmixable._ For example if your music app was running, it will stop it with that (when the first sound is played ?). Make sure you're not in silent ( _Your audio is silenced by screen locking and by the Silent switch (called the Ring/Silent switch on iPhone)_ ). Give it a try to look if this parameter fits to you.

Comment: @lchamp I am able to stop iphone's music and play my application music, Now my application music is stopped then it should resume iphone's music is it possible?
 let isOtherAudioPlaying = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().otherAudioPlaying
                if(isOtherAudioPlaying == false){
                audioPlayer1!.play()
                }